# Как участник может оставлять комментарий, не обладая необходимой репутацией?

Tags: поддержка, комментарии, репутация

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Модератор перенёс ответ в комментарии.

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]